# Can't sign in a user and shows E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express

I'm trying to register a user and save the data in the mongo database. The first one works just fine. But when I try to register another user, it shows the error:
`{"message":"E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.userdbs index: username_1 dup key: { username: null }"}`

how can I solve this?

The entry point of the app: server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport')


const connectDB = require('./server/database/connection')

const app = express()

connectDB()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'any long secret key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// routes
app.use('/', require('./server/routes/router'))

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`http://localhost:5000`)
})
```

This is the MongoDB schema for the database:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const passport = require('passport')
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose')

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true 
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

})
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)

const Userdb = new mongoose.model('userdb', userSchema)
passport.use(Userdb.createStrategy())
passport.serializeUser(Userdb.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(Userdb.deserializeUser())

module.exports = Userdb
```

This code is for saving the user data:

```
exports.registerNewUser = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Content can not be empty" });
  }
  const user = new Userdb({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
  });

  user
    .save(user)
    .then((data) => {
      res.redirect("/login");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "some error occured",
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Your code (which you really should show us, you know?) is passing in `null` as `username`, and you've set up a constraint to disallow a duplicate `username` key.

Comment: @AKX the thing is I don't really know where the error is. I've shared the server.js and the schema of MongoDB code

Comment: You aren't showing the code for your registration endpoint (which is the code that you're having problems with).

Comment: do you mean the registration ejs file for taking the inputs or the way I'm saving the data code?

Answer (score 0):

As suspected in my comment (and as the error message implies), your `registerNewUser` handler

```
exports.registerNewUser = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Content can not be empty" });
  }
  const user = new Userdb({ name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password });
  user
    .save(user)
    .then((data) => {
      res.redirect("/login");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err.message || "some error occured" });
    });
};
```

doesn't set the `username` field.

As the [documentation for the `passport-local-mongoose` package you are using says](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-mongoose#usage),

> Passport-Local Mongoose will add a username, hash and salt field to store the username, the hashed password and the salt value.

In addition, that `username` field is unique by default:

> `usernameUnique` : specifies if the username field should be enforced to be unique by a mongodb index or not. Defaults to true.

In other words, your current code succeeds on the first attempt since it creates an user with an undefined `username` (so that's `null` in MongoDB speak), and the second attempt fails because an user with a `null` username already exists.

Please read the documentation and examples for the `passport-local-mongoose` package; it looks like you're not setting the password for the user correctly either, and are storing it in plaintext when the package gives you proper salt + hash password storage.